# What determine whether an app is running under sandbox mode?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've implemented in app purchases in my app. When I test on my device , all alerts that are popped up by StoreKit have a comment in it saying that the app is running in sandbox mode.I am testing a package that I believe is a ad-hoc distribution (I use [test flight](https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/))

As far as I understands , A user that is not a "test user" can't make purchases in sand box mode. That is not what I want in a package that is distributed through the app store.

What triggers sandbox mode in the context of InApp Purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit it to the app store it will be taken out of sandbox mode.  You do not need to do anything.  I have the exact same flow in my app and use test flight.  It won't work through test flight, but apple automatically enables in-app purchase when you submit.